# ¿cómo sumar un valor a otro ya existente al activar un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, slider

La idea es que al activar el checkbox este me sume un valor cualquiera al de el id #totalv, el cual es el valor total de la suma de los 3 sliders

```js
window.addEventListener('load', main, false);

function main() {
    var n1 = document.querySelector('#num1');
    var n2 = document.querySelector('#num2');
    var n3 = document.querySelector('#num3');
    var c1 = document.querySelector('#cant1');
    var c2 = document.querySelector('#cant2');
    var c3 = document.querySelector('#cant3');
    var v1 = document.querySelector('#val1');
    var v2 = document.querySelector('#val2');
    var v3 = document.querySelector('#val3');
    var totc = document.querySelector('#totalc');
    var totv = document.querySelector('#totalv');
    var handler = function() {
        var a, b, c;
        a = ~~n1.value;
        b = ~~n2.value;
        c = ~~n3.value;
        c1.innerHTML = a;
        c2.innerHTML = b;
        c3.innerHTML = c;
        v1.innerHTML = a * 8500;
        v2.innerHTML = b * 20400;
        v3.innerHTML = c * 42500;
        totc.innerHTML = a + b + c;
        totv.innerHTML = (a * 8500) + (b * 20400) + (c * 42500);
    };
    
    /// Se puede omitir el `mousemove` pero le da un efecto
    /// de ejecucion en `tiempo real` bastante interesante
    ///n1.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
    n1.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);

    ///n2.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
    n2.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);

    ///n3.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
    n3.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);
}
```

```css
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 30%;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
        
</head>
<body>
    <input type="range" id="num1" class="slider" min="0" max="90" value="0">
    <span> Cantidad #1: <span id="cant1">0</span> <span> valor #1: $<span id="val1">0</span> </span><br><br>

    <input type="range" id="num2" class="slider" min="0" max="90" value="0">
        <span> Cantidad #2: <span id="cant2">0</span></span> <span> valor #2: $<span id="val2">0</span> </span><br><br>

    <input type="range" id="num3" class="slider" min="0" max="90" value="0">
    <span> Cantidad #3: <span id="cant3">0</span></span> <span> valor #3: $<span id="val3">0</span> </span><br><br>

    <span> Cantidad Total: <span id="totalc">0</span></span> </span> <span> valor total: $<span id="totalv">0</span> </span><br><br>
    
    <span>Checkbox: </span><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()"> <span> valor total con art: $<span id="totart">0</span> </span>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Espero esto sea lo que buscas amigo la idea es obtener el html dentro de `#totalv` convertirlo a numeros con el metodo `Number("string")` y despues sumarle el numero deseado en este caso `100000` saludos

> NOTA: pregunto en la function por `chequed` que es un parametro pasado en la llamda `myFunction(event.target.checked)` que nos retorna si esta en `checked` o no para hacer la suma o resta en caso de des chequearlo

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', main, false);

function  myFunction(checked){

  if(checked){
    document.querySelector("#totalv").innerHTML =    Number(document.querySelector("#totalv").innerHTML) + 100000
  } else {
  document.querySelector("#totalv").innerHTML =    Number(document.querySelector("#totalv").innerHTML) - 100000
  }
  
}

function main() {
    var n1 = document.querySelector('#num1');
    var n2 = document.querySelector('#num2');
    var n3 = document.querySelector('#num3');
    var c1 = document.querySelector('#cant1');
    var c2 = document.querySelector('#cant2');
    var c3 = document.querySelector('#cant3');
    var v1 = document.querySelector('#val1');
    var v2 = document.querySelector('#val2');
    var v3 = document.querySelector('#val3');
    var totc = document.querySelector('#totalc');
    var totv = document.querySelector('#totalv');
    var handler = function() {
        var a, b, c;
        a = ~~n1.value;
        b = ~~n2.value;
        c = ~~n3.value;
        c1.innerHTML = a;
        c2.innerHTML = b;
        c3.innerHTML = c;
        v1.innerHTML = a * 8500;
        v2.innerHTML = b * 20400;
        v3.innerHTML = c * 42500;
        totc.innerHTML = a + b + c;
        totv.innerHTML = (a * 8500) + (b * 20400) + (c * 42500);
    };
    
    /// Se puede omitir el `mousemove` pero le da un efecto
    /// de ejecucion en `tiempo real` bastante interesante
    ///n1.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
    n1.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);

    ///n2.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
    n2.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);

    ///n3.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
    n3.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);
}
```

```css
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 30%;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
        
</head>
<body>
    <input type="range" id="num1" class="slider" min="0" max="90" value="0">
    <span> Cantidad #1: <span id="cant1">0</span> <span> valor #1: $<span id="val1">0</span> </span><br><br>

    <input type="range" id="num2" class="slider" min="0" max="90" value="0">
        <span> Cantidad #2: <span id="cant2">0</span></span> <span> valor #2: $<span id="val2">0</span> </span><br><br>

    <input type="range" id="num3" class="slider" min="0" max="90" value="0">
    <span> Cantidad #3: <span id="cant3">0</span></span> <span> valor #3: $<span id="val3">0</span> </span><br><br>

    <span> Cantidad Total: <span id="totalc">0</span></span> </span> <span> valor total: $<span id="totalv">0</span> </span><br><br>
    
    <span>Checkbox: </span><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction(event.target.checked)"> <span> valor total con art: $<span id="totart">0</span> </span>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Luis, muchas gracias, es perfecto, ahora tengo otro problema, cambie el ID #totalv por #totart para visualizar el valor al lado del checkbox, que tendría que modificar para que el valor variara en tiempo real si deslizo los Sliders?

Comment: Tienes que sumarle el valor del html dentro de `#totart` y listo o eso creo que es lo que quieres

Comment: la cuestión es que si hago si cambia, pero no en tiempo real, si no cada vez que desmarque o marque el checkbox!

Comment: lo que quieres es que se duplique el valor a agregar o algo asi si esta marcado el checkbox?